# Unable to have Azure AD B2C issue a token and redirect it to https://jwt.ms

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Back in a few months ago, I registered an app in Azure AD B2C, defined identity experience policies and had the token decoded by https://jwt.ms successfully. I followed the steps outlines in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga), [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and also [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga) and it led me to success.

I needed to create another Azure AD B2C directory for a client and repeated the same steps in those articles to at least get the tokens decoded by https://jwt.ms but no luck at all! I am really baffled by why I keep getting the following screen when trying to run the policy despite I defined https://jwt.ms as a reply URL:

[image]

Could you please guide me what I am missing in this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only happens if you don’t have an AAD B2C application registration created in the directory.

Follow this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga

The key step is this

*Under Supported account types, select Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows).*

Comment: But why is that? Would you be able to have the documentation amended?

Comment: Because that is the only type of app compatible, and you need a clientId to make an OIDC auth request. Without an app reg, you can’t populate that blade. Specifically what doc needs amending?